# PHP RSS based schedule

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match

I've been stuck on this for awhile here. I'm trying to build a function that retrieves schedule information based on what day it is (the RSS feed has the next 10 days in advanced)

The problem is sifting through the RSS feed to remove the data I don't want - for example 24th Jan 2011 : Day 7 needs to be 7.

So when I use

```
<?php echo schedule('01/24/2011'); ?>
```

It calls this:

```
//Finds the day by stripping data from the myDragonnet RSS feed.
function schedule($given_date) {
    $url = "http://mydragonnet.hkis.edu.hk/schedule/day_schedule_rss.php?schedule_id=1";
    $rss = simplexml_load_file($url);
    $date = date("~jS M Y~", strtotime($given_date)); 
    if($rss) {
        foreach($rss->channel->item as $item) {
            foreach ($item->title as $story) {
                if (strpos($date, $story) !== false) {
                    preg_match("/Day (\d+)/", $story, $m);
                    break; // stop searching
                }   
            } 
        }
    }
    return $m[1];
}
```

But the problem is I'm continuously  getting - `Notice: Undefined variable: m in ***/class.schedule.php on line 38`

Comment: Looking at the RSS feed you're pulling, that regular expression won't always work either, as the day name is not always numeric ("Day C2").

Comment: I had it working previously - if any non-numerical day was set it would default to a special schedule later on in the code. Also on weekends when no day is present this would be used here:   if (empty($m)) {
 $m[1] = 0;
}

Answer (score 3):

You're copying and pasting from answers to your other questions without understanding.

Your `preg_match` line which would populate `$m` (if there were a match) cannot be reached, since you're passing a regular expression pattern to `strpos` and it's always returning false.

The `~` delimiters around the pattern don't appear in your RSS feed as literal characters, so strpos is never going to find them.

Comment: Slow down, examine your code one line at a time, figure out what you were trying to do with that line, and determine whether it actually does that. If you think it's correct, write code to test your assumptions. If you did that, you'd know that your preg_match line was never reached. You'll find your mistakes.

Comment: Well I was working on this for a good hour before I came here - breaking the code down. It's just now that it's gotten increasingly frustrated.

Comment: Well I've got it working now - trying to figure out the best method for unusual days (C2 for example). Thanks for putting up with the antics.